# Wordpress crops images differently on retina screens?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, cropping

I am currently testing my websites on different types of screens and while my image cropping works perfectly on a non-retina screen, I am running into some cropping issues on retina screens.

I have two image sizes that are cropped to different dimensions. To achieve this, I have this in my functions.php file:

```
add_image_size('sidebar-thumbnail', 70, 70, true);
add_image_size('small-thumbnail', 300, 180, true);
```

On non-retina screens, the images crop perfectly for both sizes. However, on retina screens, the images look squished on one of the two sizes, for example:

[image: retina small thumbnail]
[image: retina sidebar thumbnail]

the sidebar-thumbnail is squished horizontally to fit in the square. In other examples, the sidebar-thumbnail looks fine but the small-thumbnail is stretched horizontally to fit the size. This is confusing to me because on standard-resolution screens both thumbnails are cropped perfectly, even when the same two images are displaying wrong on retina. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Can you please confirm the screenshot of those images using a default WP Theme? Or, alternatively being in `/wp-content/uploads/YYYY/MM/` with file names `filename-300x180.ext` and `filename-70x70.ext` - and opening both the images using an image viewer like Picassa or ACDSee. We need this to ensure that your theme is not squeezing those images while showing on front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that what was causing this issue was a plugin I had enabled that was supposed to handle retina images called [WP Retina 2X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/). I disabled the plugin and it immediately fixed the issue.